# Referencing to a subform text field

Tags: ms-access

I know it is a simple problem and I should be able to google it and work it out myself, yet 2 hours later and I still cannot get my head around this simple problem.

I have:

Navigation Form called "Menu2"

Form called "Red Tag"

Field in Red Tag called "Nr" and "Tekst149"

I now that I do not call "Red Tag" but use its control name which is "PodformularzNawigacji".

I tried:

```
   Forms![Menu2].[PodformularzNawigacji].Form.[Nr] Like Forms![Menu2].[PodformularzNawigacji].Form.[Tekst149]
```

Or

```
Forms![Menu2].[PodformularzNawigacji].Form.[Nr] Like Forms![Menu2].[PodformularzNawigacji].Form.[Tekst149]
```

Or

```
Forms![Menu2]![PodformularzNawigacji]![Nr] like Forms![Menu2]![PodformularzNawigacji]![Tekst149]
```

And many more but without success. I do not have English version of Access, perhaps that also the problem (of course I don't use "Forms" but its equivalent in my language)

Edit: 
The problem is that this reference is incorrect "This form is not connected to any table or a query". When I had this form as a stand alone form everything worked it was only:

```
[Nr] Like Forms![Red Tag]![Tekst152]
```

Comment: Could you better explain what the problem is? you have explained that SOMETHING doesn't work, but haven't explained what you are trying to achieve nor what is happening that you weren't expecting

Comment: edited my original post

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
Forms![Menu2]![PodformularzNawigacji].Form![Nr] Like Forms![Menu2]![PodformularzNawigacji].Form![Tekst149]
```

Comment: The same problem, but excel automatically transforms it to:
`[Nr] Like [Formularze]![Menu2]![PodformularzNawigacji].[Form]![Tekst149]`
So im not sure if command "Form" works in Polish. Access automatically translates Forms to  Formularze, but leaves Form in its original form.

Comment: Then try Formularze in singularis for Form.